# Showing Syntax Error : Invalid Syntax for Print Statement on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
counter = 0
for a in oldCols:
    counter += 1
    calc = round((data[a].isna().sum() / len(data[a])) * 100, 2)
    print((f'{calc}% - Colno: {counter}'))
    if calc > 50:
        #         print(counter)
        toRemove.append(a)
```

This is my Code for Removing NAN columns.

However, the error showing up is

```
File "<ipython-input-24-cefb2bf286aa>", line 5
    print((f'{calc}% - Colno: {counter}'))
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone help? I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: Is your notebook using Python 3.6+?

Comment: It'd be helpful to build a [mre] -- code that's complete enough to work on its own. Right now nobody else can run this in their own interpreter to see the error or test proposed fixes, because the code requires a `data` variable it doesn't create, and an `oldCols` variable likewise. Can you still get the same error if you hardcode `calc = 3`? If not, you know you need to take a close look at the line assigning `calc`. How about `oldCols = [0]`?

Comment: ...and yes, the specific Python (kernel version, in the case of Jupyter) needs to be included in the question.

Comment: @BallpointBen No I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: @CharlesDuffy https://github.com/SubhadityaMukherjee/kaggleOSMI-MentalHealth/blob/master/mentalHealth.ipynb 

this is the project I was trying to understand & implement. Exact Code by code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2.x we didn't have f-strings, this won't work:

```
f'{calc}% - Colno: {counter}'
```

Try this instead:

```
'{}% - Colno: {}'.format(calc, counter)
```

Comment: Absolute Gold stuff. Thank you so much. Godspeed.

Comment: I did. Thanks a lot. :)